# Should I move the std::exchange ed members?

Tags: c++, c++14, move-constructor

The `std::exchange` can be used to impliment the move constructors. Here is an example from the cppreference.com https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/exchange#Notes.

However, the possible implimenation of the `std::exchange` looks like this:

```
template<class T, class U = T>
T exchange(T& obj, U&& new_value)
{
    T old_value = std::move(obj);
    obj = std::forward<U>(new_value);
    return old_value;          // can be copy (until C++17) or a move (C++17), right?
}
```

Now my situation:

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>

struct MyClass
{
    std::string m_str;
    // some other non-primitive members of the class

    MyClass(MyClass&& other) : m_str{ std::exchange(other.m_str, {}) } // enough?
        // or
        // : m_str{ std::move(std::exchange(other.m_str, {})) }
        //          ^^^^^^^^^^    do i need to move?                          
    {}

    MyClass& operator=(MyClass&& other)
    {
        this->m_str = std::exchange(other.m_str, {}); // enough?
        // or 
        // this->m_str = std::move( std::exchange(other.m_str, {}) );
        //               ^^^^^^^^^^    do I need to move?   
        return *this;
    }
};
```

As I commented on the code, there is a chance for move or copy by the lines

```
m_str{ std::exchange(other.m_str, {}) }
this->m_str = std::exchange(other.m_str, nullptr);
```

Therefore,

- should I use explicitly `std::move` for them, so that I can make sure
  that the members have been 100% moved to the `other` object?
- If **Yes**, will it be more verbous to use `std::exchange` for this
  scenario?

I am using visual studio 2017 with compiler flag C++14.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, using `std::move` is not necessary here. Rule of thumb is - if some returned value is not assigned to a variable it will be moved.

```
template<class T, class U = T>
T exchange(T& obj, U&& new_value)
{
    T old_value = std::move(obj);
    obj = std::forward<U>(new_value);
    return old_value;          // will be moved if move constructor defined
    // or even copy will be elided and will be no constructor call
}
```

The move is guaranteed here contrary to what you say. C++17 changes copy elision rules but that's something different

From [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) you can see that prvalue is:

> function call or an overloaded operator expression, whose return type
>   is non-reference, such as str.substr(1, 2), str1 + str2, or it++

And properties of prvalues (as subset of rvalues) are (emphasis mine):

> An rvalue may be used to **initialize an rvalue reference**, in which case
>   the lifetime of the object identified by the rvalue is extended until
>   the scope of the reference ends.
>
> When used as a function argument and when two overloads of the
>   function are available, **one taking rvalue reference parameter and the
>   other taking lvalue reference to const parameter, an rvalue binds to
>   the rvalue reference overload** (thus, if both copy and move
>   constructors are available, an rvalue argument invokes the move
>   constructor, and likewise with copy and move assignment operators).

Comment: In other words, the above qestion can be capsuled as follows: This `this->m_str = std::exchange(other.m_str, {});` can be interpreted as `some_var = some_func()`. Is it gurateed to be always a **move** , eventhough it is an assignment operation (since C++14)?

Comment: It is guaranteed even since C++11 since it assigns from rvalue

Comment: Thanks... Looks promising. Still, I will wait two days, just to see if others have any comments on this question. Meanwhile, would be nice, if you could add the relevant citation to your answer.